# How to get HTML content from servlet to ajax success call by jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call to servlet , that construct a HTML dropdown in server side and retrun the same to client, i.e. jQuery Ajax call. Then how to get the response . my Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/tool/updateTagMap",
        data :  "submit=getTagList",
        datatype : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

And server side code

```
   else if ("getTagList".equalsIgnoreCase(submit)) {
     List<Tag> tagList = DBUtil.getTagList();
     String tagCombo ="<select name='tagId' class='tagIdClass'>";
     for(Tag tag : tagList ){
       tagCombo += "<option value=" + tag .getTagId() +">"+ tag.getTag()+ "</option>";
     }
     tagCombo += " </select>";
     response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     response.getWriter().write(tagCombo);
  }
```

But in alert i am getting the whole HTML? any idea? How to get the drop-down html only?

Comment: in your response you will get HTML and then create a html element like div on your  page and write your response in page document.

Comment: not clear. can you please explain a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like you have a div with id="dummydiv"

and you get the response of ajax in variable data
then you need to do that.
     $('#dummydiv').html(data);

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the relationship between Ajax success queries, the JSON return object and how to apply it to the Document Object Model of the web page.

In your ajax method, you have a line

```
dataType : "json"
```

This is telling `jQuery.ajax()` to expect a return in the format of a Javascript Object Notation object in the format

```
{
  key0 : value0,
  key1 : value 1,
  ...  : ...
  keyn : value n
}
```

In order to apply this to the DOM, imagine that you have the following HTML on your page:

```
<div id = 'select_container'
  <select id = 'dropdown_select'></select>
</div>
```

If your JSON return is valid, you can do something in your `success` function similar to

```
success : function(data){
  var appendString = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    appendString += "<option id = 'option_" + i + "' >" + data[i].value + "</option>";

  $("#dropdown_select").append(appendString);
}
```

This sample takes in a valid JSON return object, builds a string of valid HTML and uses the `append()` method to apply it to the select dropdown list.  If the list is empty, then the contents of the success function will be applied from 0 .. n, but if the list already has option values, the new elements will be added at the end of the dropdown select options.

Your issue is that you are returning HTML in your Ajax query method.  Convert it to return the names, ids and other information into valid JSON to apply the DOM elements that are affected by this query.